# Csv in pandas with a json column

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm a newbie on Python, but I'm trying to read this csv into a pandas dataframe. From what I'm knowing at the moment, I've tried using json_normalize but I receive errors. Can someone help or give me a direction what I could do to get the desired result?

```
d = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
normd = json_normalize(d['Genre'])
```

**.csv**

```
Id, Genre
237000000,[ {""id"": 28, ""name"": ""Action""}, 
            {""id"": 12, ""name"": ""Adventure""}, 
            {""id"": 14, ""name"": ""Fantasy""}, 
            {""id"": 878, ""name"": ""Science Fiction""} ]
```

**Result dataframe**

```
Id         GenreId  GenreName
237000000  28       Action
237000000  12       Adventure
237000000  14       Fantasy
237000000  878      Science Fiction
```

**Error**

```
AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-62-b221c2f04868> in <module>() 
----> 1 normd = json_normalize(d['Genre'])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\normalize.py in json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep)
181 
182     if record_path is None:
--> 183         if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in compat.itervalues(data[0])]):
184             # naive normalization, this is idempotent for flat records
185             # and potentially will inflate the data considerably for

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py in itervalues(obj, **kw)
182 
183     def itervalues(obj, **kw):
--> 184         return iter(obj.values(**kw))
185 
186     next = next

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: Can you show what errors you are receiving?

Comment: @JanTrienes Updated post with error

Comment: @Kevin, please provide some feedback if the answer below did not help in solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way that second column is structured makes it impossible to bring in the data with a comma as a separator. The second column has both commas and newline characters in it. Therefore, your best bet is to import the whole thing as a string and do some cleaning by targeting the `json` and converting it into a python data structure. Working with the snippet of csv data you posted, the following imports the data as a string and then splits each line by a newline character ***not followed*** by a comma. This basically means any newline character that constitutes a true line break, avoiding the newline characters inside the `json` part of the text. Once that's done, it proceeds to splitting each element of the resulting list on a comma ***not followed*** by a space or newline character. Again, this is done to avoid splitting on the commas inside the `json` part of the text.
At this point, you have a list of lists; each sublist has 2 elements: an ID value and a `json` text. So, you can skip the first sublist and iterate through the remaining sublists. At every iteration, you will need to convert the `json` text into a python list of dictionaries and loop through this list of dictionaries to edit them with what you want your desired output to contain. See below for the illustration:

```
import json
import re
import pandas as pd


with open('complex.csv') as f:
    data = []
    text = f.read()
    records = [re.split(",(?![ \n]+)", x.replace('""', '"')) for x in re.split("(?<!, )\n", text)]
    for r in records[1:]:
        second_col = json.loads(r[1])
        for d in second_col:
            d['GenreId'] = d['id']
            d['Id'] = r[0]
            del d['id']
            d['GenreName'] = d['name']
            del d['name']
        data += second_col
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)


print(df)


#    GenreId        GenreName         Id
# 0       28           Action  237000000
# 1       12        Adventure  237000000
# 2       14          Fantasy  237000000
# 3      878  Science Fiction  237000000
```

#### The contents of `complex.csv`:

```
Id, Genre
237000000,[ {""id"": 28, ""name"": ""Action""}, 
            {""id"": 12, ""name"": ""Adventure""}, 
            {""id"": 14, ""name"": ""Fantasy""}, 
            {""id"": 878, ""name"": ""Science Fiction""} ]
```

I hope this helps.